# How does the placement of "nicht" change the example?

Tags: word-usage, word-order, adverb

I was curious if these sentences meant the same thing and if they were both valid. The first sentence I made myself, the second is what I heard.

Does the meaning change with the different placement of *nicht*?

> Es tut mir Leid, dass Du mit mir nicht kommen kannst.
>    Es tut mir Leid, dass Du nicht mit mir kommen kannst.

Comment: The first version sounds weird/wrong. Also, this phrasing with "mit mir kommen" does not sound all to idiomatic to my ears but rather like an English speaker translating "come with me"

Comment: I was under the impression that my wording on the first sentence would be wrong. However, I've seen and heard mit mir kommen" in various sentences a lot. I'm confused as to why it could be wrong. :(

Comment: It sounds weird, but it's possible. Look at my answer.

Comment: Well, by wrong I mean "not idiomatic". I would never say that. I would use "mitkommen" without any "mir" anywhere. That doesn't mean that no German speaker ever uses it. I do know that "Mit jemandem kommen" is at least used in literature.

Comment: See, now that's helpful. Give me an example of a more commonly used phrased. :) I have learned mitkommen as well and am glad to know that's more common. Thank you! :) also please, if you ever see me post a sentence using a rare phrasing please let me know.

Comment: `mit mir kommen` is certainly literatic but also old style spoken language (maybe by people who like to sound literatic). You might provoke Emanuel's reaction, but in principle this is not only correct but also high register.

Comment: It's interesting to find this stuff out. I've really enjoy all this input so far. It's funny that so much could be said for changing the placement of nicht. I wish I had some sort of nicht placement drill I could do. Also, I learned the mit mir kommen from a 80 year old man, Michel Thomas. Perhaps that's why it sounds dated. :) still... His example was correct and mine wasn't. All due to me not understanding nicht placement. Anyway I want to thank you all go your input! :)

Comment: @Emanuel The first version could be OK if it's about having sex.

Comment: It's somewhat off-topic, but here's an example (from a famous German comedian, Heinz Erhardt) showing the importance of a comma (or pausing when reading aloud) in combination with "nicht": "*Was ist am Haifisch denn das Schöne? Die Flossen nicht, die Zähne!*" (Or maybe it is "*Die Flossen, nicht die Zähne!*", I'm not sure ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Es tut mir Leid, dass Du mit mir nicht kommen kannst.

What I understand is that this sentence really underlines "mit mir" (with me). The person is really sorry that the other can't come with him. So the other person has to go with someone else he doesn't like for example.

> Es tut mir Leid, dass Du nicht mit mir kommen kannst.

This is the general form for saying, that you cannot come with me. It is neutral compared to the first one.

Comment: The first example gives "kommen" a strange emphasis as the statement would be that "you" can't do it with "me" (but perhaps with someone else) – with exactly that sexual undertone. Thus, unless you want to translate the English slang expression "cum", you wouldn't want to prefer that alternative to the second one, which is the proper way to say "I'm sorry you can't come with me".

Comment: @Martin Schwehla It might be a bit far-fetched but it makes absolutely sense. I hadn't thought about this statement of the sentence.

Answer (score 4):

There are three different verbs to think of here:

1. `mit jemandem kommen`=`come with somebody` The `mit jemandem` is an obligatory object here.
2. `kommen`=`come, arrive, …` Has no obligatory objects.
3. `kommen`=`cum, get to orgasm` Has no obligatory objects.

Negation usually encompasses a verb with all its obligatory objects. So for the first verb the usually negated sentence is your second proposal:

> Es tut mir Leid, dass Du nicht mit mir kommen kannst.

Observe, that verb and obligatory object stay together and are not separated by `nicht`.

On the other hand, if `nicht` separates the `kommen` and `mit mir` as in your second proposal

> Es tut mir Leid, dass Du mit mir nicht kommen kannst.

then there are several possible meanings associated with that:

- It's still the first verb, but there is heavy emphasis on the object `mit mir`. With somebody else the addressee might come.
- It's the second verb and `mit mir` is a modal adverbial. This is rather strange because there is only minimal difference to the first verb.
- It's the third verb and `mit mir` is a modal adverbial. This is perfectly fine considering the grammar.

As the first verb is rather uncommon in spoken language (except maybe for high registers) and the second sound strange here, most people will guess the third meaning (at least if they know that meaning of `kommen`).

**Beware:** For all possible verbs, the position of `nicht` sets an emphasis that may alternatively be conveyed by stressing the respective words.

Answer (score 4):

I would translate the sentences as followed:

> Es tut mir Leid, dass Du mit mir nicht kommen kannst.

`I'm sorry that you can't cum with me.`

> Es tut mir Leid, dass Du nicht mit mir kommen kannst.

`I'm sorry that you can't come with me.`

Answer (score 0):

The given explanations may or may not be grammatically correct but they are purely academic. No native german speaker would ever say "Es tut mir Leid, dass Du mit mir nicht kommen kannst." The "nicht" needs to go before "mit mir", everything else is plain wrong (in the sense of "nobody uses it that way").

Also, this wrong order of words is not suitable for putting a special stress on the "mit mir". It does not work that way it German. The only thing you can do to empasize when speaking is to raise your voice a bit for the "mir" part. If you wanted to stress the "mir" part in written language you would need to use a different construct alltogether, such as "statt dessen (instead)": Es tut mir Leid, dass Du nicht statt dessen mit mir kommen kannst.

Oh - in a sexual context you would probably want to use "zusammen mit mir" (together with me) rather than "instead". :-)  Other tahn that, all of the above applies there, too.

Comment: how does "statt dessen" or "zusammen" put stress on *mir*? Depending on the context, it might change the meaning, especially "statt dessen".

Comment: in the sense of "oh you had to go with xy? I am sorry that you could not come with me instead".  That stresses the me part.Or "I am happy that you came together with me".